# How to build mathematical function using these two timedelta variables?

Tags: python, function, pandas, datetime, graph

I have these two variables

```
df['duration_A'] =  ['2 days 04:07:02.497200','2 days 05:07:02.497200','NaT' , '1 days 02:58:17.073600', '1 days 14:33:17.073600', '2 days 10:08:17.073600']
df['duration_B'] = ['1 days 21:08:17.073600','2 days 21:08:17.021600','1 days 17:58:17.077600','1 days 01:01:17.075430','0 days 21:08:17.089600','1 days 21:08:17.045600']
```

The datatype of duration_A is  object

The datatype of duration_B is timedelta64[ns]

I would like to plot a graph between them and construct a mathematical function (like plotting a graph between these two variables and determining the function) ?
So that if i have one variable, i can determine the other variable .

Comment: What kind of plot are you looking for? What do you mean by "determining the function"?

Comment: i have similar datas. so i am trying to determine a function based on the trend. so that , in future if i know one of the variable i can determine the other!

Comment: The question isn't clear at all. Are you looking for a time series?

Comment: i need to determine a function , so that if i have date of one variable, i can determine the other variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot duration_A against duration_B, you can transform your data to numerical values using datetime.timedelta.total_seconds() and then plot the values against each other. Based on what you have written, I'm assuming your data is of type datetime.timedelta. I'm not going to do anything with the NaT in your example -- you can choose to drop them, fill them with a dummy value, or interpolate them as you find best.

```
import datetime
from matplotlib import pylot as plt
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'A': [datetime.timedelta(days=2, hours=4, minutes=7, seconds=2.49700), datetime.timedelta(days=2, hours=5, minutes=7, seconds=2.4972)],'B': [datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=21, minutes=8, seconds=17.07360), datetime.timedelta(days=2, hours=21, minutes=8, seconds=17.0216)]})
data['A_seconds'] = data['A'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
data['B_seconds'] = data['B'].apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds())
plt.plot(ex['A_seconds'], ex['B_seconds'])
```

Once you have the plot, you can use whatever method looks appropriate to fit a model - for example, if it looks linear, you can run a regression using a package like statsmodels.